# x color error in tikzpgfmanual

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, color

I'm want to create a flowchart in Latex(sharelatex.com). But to try out what i need to do i start with creating a copy from the manual.
The example is shown on Page 147 in [tikzpgfmanual.pdf](http://paws.wcu.edu/tsfoguel/tikzpgfmanual.pdf).
First start a copy where i figured out that i was missing some packages and libraries. After fixing these packages i still get errors on some lines. Basically on every path(i left one open). The errors i got are

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> \OT1\textquoteright
```

and

```
Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `latex\OT1\textquoteright '.
See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.
```

My tikz script so far.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
    \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20, text width=4.5em, text badly centered, inner sep=1pt]
    \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20,text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
    \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, thick, -latex’,shorten >=2pt];
    \tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw=red, thick, ellipse,fill=red!20, minimum height=2em];
    \matrix [column sep=5mm,row sep=7mm]
    {
    % row 1
    \node [cloud] (expert) {expert}; &
    \node [block] (init) {initialize model}; &
    \node [cloud] (system) {system}; \\
    % row 2
    & \node [block] (identify) {identify candidate model}; & \\
    % row 3
    \node [block] (update) {update model}; &
    \node [block] (evaluate) {evaluate candidate models}; & \\
    % row 4
    & \node [decision] (decide) {is best candidate}; & \\
    % row 5
    & \node [block] (stop) {stop}; & \\
    };
    \tikzstyle{every path}=[line]
    \path (init) -- (identify);
    %\path (identify) -- (evaluate);
    %\path (evaluate) -- (decide);
    %\path (update) |- (identify);
    %\path (decide) -| node [near start] {yes} (update);
    %\path (decide) -- node [midway] {no} (stop);
    %\path [dashed] (expert) -- (init);
    %\path [dashed] (system) -- (init);
    %\path [dashed] (system) |- (evaluate);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have the idea i'm missing some package but i'm unable to figure out which one. If i'm don't miss a package can somebody explain what's wrong?

Comment: You have curly quotes where you need straight ones: not `-latex’` but `-latex'`. Better still, use `arrows.meta`.

Comment: Don't copy text from PDF and paste it into your code. Rewrite the quotes and dashes, for example. When you copy/paste usually you have problems. So it is better to avoid.

Comment: You need the library \usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,shapes}

Comment: @AndréC Yes, not really, no. The `latex'` arrow tip is defined in the `arrows` library, there is nothing in the code that requires `arrows.meta` (which is a newer library, but the old `arrows` is actually considered deprecated in favor of `arrows.meta`, so switching should be considered). And he already loads `shapes.geometric`, which is sufficient for the code in the question.

Comment: `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, too. The manual is not always up-to-date with its recommendations.

Comment: Don't read that specific manual though, it's *ancient*. The current version of `pgf`/TikZ is 3.0.1a, a lot has happened since 1.18. Look at CTAN, or [texdoc.net](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) instead.

Comment: Yes I shall change them

Comment: @cfr Do you want to answer?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Done. Though it hardly seems answer-worthy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems. The first is that the curly closing quotation mark is not part of Ti*k*Z syntax, so `-latex’` gives an error. It is presumably the straight quotation mark which you want in the arrow specification `-latex'`.

The second problem is that the arrow tip kind `latex` is not defined by default. To use it, you must load the `arrows` library. However, this is deprecated, so it would be better to use `arrows.meta` instead.

`\tikzstyle` is also deprecated, so it would also be better to update this syntax, too.

Recommended code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows.meta}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    auto,
    decision/.style={diamond, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20, text width=4.5em, text badly centered, inner sep=1pt},
    block/.style={rectangle, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20,text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
    line/.style={draw, thick, -Latex,shorten >=2pt},
    cloud/.style={draw=red, thick, ellipse,fill=red!20, minimum height=2em},
  ]
  \matrix [column sep=5mm,row sep=7mm]
  {
    \node [cloud] (expert) {expert}; &
    \node [block] (init) {initialize model}; &
    \node [cloud] (system) {system}; \\
    & \node [block] (identify) {identify candidate model}; & \\
    \node [block] (update) {update model}; &
    \node [block] (evaluate) {evaluate candidate models}; & \\
    & \node [decision] (decide) {is best candidate}; & \\
    & \node [block] (stop) {stop}; & \\
  };
  \tikzset{every path/.style={line}}
  \path (init) -- (identify);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: compiled output]

Minimally amended code in case you don't want to use the recommendation above for some reason:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
  \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20, text width=4.5em, text badly centered, inner sep=1pt]
  \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20,text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
  \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, thick, -latex',shorten >=2pt];
  \tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw=red, thick, ellipse,fill=red!20, minimum height=2em];
  \matrix [column sep=5mm,row sep=7mm]
  {
    \node [cloud] (expert) {expert}; &
    \node [block] (init) {initialize model}; &
    \node [cloud] (system) {system}; \\
    & \node [block] (identify) {identify candidate model}; & \\
    \node [block] (update) {update model}; &
    \node [block] (evaluate) {evaluate candidate models}; & \\
    & \node [decision] (decide) {is best candidate}; & \\
    & \node [block] (stop) {stop}; & \\
  };
  \tikzstyle{every path}=[line]
  \path (init) -- (identify);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wish you a merry Christmas!

Comment: @samcarter Nadolig Llawen!